# What this sound is doing with water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, frequency, flow, vibrations

I saw a video on youtube with link  "https://youtube.com/watch?v=uENITui5_jU"

In the video a stream of water is run from a nozzle attached to a speaker diaphragm. The speaker plays a 24Hz sinusoidal tone, which is the same frequency as the shutter on the camera filming the video. With the speaker playing, the video appears to show the stream of water frozen in a zigzag or wave shape.

Is there someone kind enough to explain what is happening in the video I mean by science used.

Comment: [Harmonics and Patterns](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-4/Harmonics-and-Patterns)

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The speaker is vibrating the nozzle back and forth so the stream of water of course oscillates back and forth with it, just like if you turn on a water house and wave it around by hand.

The reason the stream seems to be "frozen" in a certain configuration is that the frequency of the sound wave and the frequency of the camera shutter are the same - 24 Hz. This is specified in the introductory setup in the video. Multiples of 24 Hz would display similarly but with "multiple streams" visible. However if you were to view the stream in person, it would simply appear to be bouncing about wildly because our eyes capture images at a much higher rate than 24 Hz.